# Do I have to be a mathematician to understand the following papers?

Tags: svd, clustering

I come from a CS&Machine Learning discipline. I have been looking to understand the core idea of Non-Negative Matrix Factorization. While most of the ML based work is understandable, mostly the work boils down to theoretical papers. Some examples are:

"On the Equivalence of Nonnegative Matrix Factorization and
Spectral Clustering"

"SVD based initialization:Ahead start for nonnegative matrix factorization"

However, the papers seem to be quite scary. Do I really have to be a mathematician to understand the following papers? Or if not, which coursework would speed up digging into aforementioned papers?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the amount of mathematics you are comfortable dealing with ? Once that is clearly known, we could suggest correct background to pick up. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: I have taken advanced calculus course few years ago. I am quite familiar with fundamental linear algebra, probability theory and random processes, supplemented with tiny amount of knowledge in control theory. I have not taken any course on math background such as abstract algebra or analysis.

I would say most of the time I can understand derivations in my field since I know that they are quite limited in math, but when it goes to lemmas, propositions, and theorems such as those papers, I have the feeling that I do not know where to start. I would like to make at least baby steps here.

Comment: *the papers seem to be quite scary* - Be afraid. Be very afraid. ;-$)$

Comment: You already know much more than what might be required. Just jump into it right away.